# Cassandra: Does timeuuid preserve order?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql, timeuuid

I was using timestamp as primary key for my data by calling `toTimestamp(now())`, but unfortunately this creates collision.

I understand that timeuuid guarantees uniqueness, but if I do `ORDER BY timeuuid`, does timeuuid also guarantee the original order?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

Timeuuid types can be entered as integers for CQL input. A value of the timeuuid type is a Version 1 UUID. **A Version 1 UUID includes the time of its generation and are sorted by timestamp, making them ideal for use in applications requiring conflict-free timestamps.** For example, you can use this type to identify a column (such as a blog entry) by its timestamp and allow multiple clients to write to the same partition key simultaneously. Collisions that would potentially overwrite data that was not intended to be overwritten cannot occur.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html